# jQuery — Toggle to state other than default?

Tags: jquery

If i use the code:

```
    $('.myDiv').toggle();
```

With the initial state as:

> .mydiv {display:none}

How can I state that the toggle must go to

> .mydiv {display:table}

?

Currently it just goes to a default block.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a css class for the display:

```
.myDiv { display: table; }
.noDisplay { display: none; }
```

Then use .toggleClass() to toggle the class:

```
$('.myDiv').toggleClass("noDisplay");
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use toggle to do that. You will need to actually use `.css("display","table")`

Kyle's method is probably a bit faster.